# The action of $SL(2, \mathbb R)$ on $\mathbb R^4$ though Clifford algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions, quaternions, clifford-algebras

> My question is about the realization of $SL(2, \mathbb R)$ as the group of unit
> quaternions in the even-dimensional Clifford algebra corresponding to an anisotropic quadratic form on $\mathbb R^3$ (from the paper ANOSOV FLOWS ON INFRA-HOMOGENEOUS
> SPACES by PER TOMTER, page 300), so that $SL(2, \mathbb R)$ can act on $\mathbb R^4$.

Let $V=\mathbb R^3$ and $Q$ be a to-be-determined (?) quadratic form on $V$ free of nonzero integer solutions. The Clifford algebra $\mathcal A$ is defined as the quotient of the tensor algebra

$$\oplus_{n\ge 0} V^{\otimes n}$$

by the two-sided ideal $\langle v\otimes v - Q(v)1 \mid v\in V \rangle$, where $1$ is the unit of $\oplus_{n\ge 0} V^{\otimes n}$.

But I have some difficulty understanding the meaning of "realization of $SL(2, \mathbb R)$ as the group of unit quaternions in the even-dimensional Clifford algebra" in this situation. I guess in order to construct an action of $SL(2, \mathbb R)$ on $\mathbb R^4$ though Clifford algebra, we have to choose $Q$ in such a way (really?) that $\mathcal A$ is a 4-dimensional(or some even-dimensional) real algebra with basis $1,i,j,k$ and embed $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ into $A$ by identifying the matrices in $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ with $a+bi+cj+dk$. My understanding might be wrong, but how is this constructed specifically?

I hope my question is not confusing, but if you know any other ways of defining the action of $SL(2, \mathbb R)$ on $\mathbb R^4$, though Clifford algebra or not, please feel free to share. Thanks!

Comment: Every nontrivial Clifford algebra is even dimensional. If they mean the even subalgebra, both even subalgebras $C\ell_0(3,0)$ and $C\ell_0(3,0)$ are $\cong\Bbb H$, the quaternions. (I assume we speak of real algebras.) The unit quaternions $S^3={\rm Sp}(1)\cong{\rm SU}(2)$ are a compact real form of ${\rm SL}(2,\Bbb C)$, while the unit split quaternions ${\rm SL}(2,\Bbb R)$ are the split real form. You will not find ${\rm SL}(2,\Bbb R)$ in these subalgebras. The only $m$-dim real irrep of ${\rm SL}(2,\Bbb R)$ is ${\rm Sym}^{m-1}\Bbb R^2$, so you can classify the 4D real reps this way I think.

Answer (score 3):

First, there are varying conventions about formation of a Clifford algebra attached to a quadratic form. Some conventions have a sign flipped in comparison to others, so the implications of isotropic/anisotropic are ambiguous.

But that does not affect the facts. :)

Let's take the convention that the Clifford algebra associated to a quadratic form $Q$ is characterized by $v\cdot v=Q(v)$. Thus, the Hamiltonian quaternions appear as the Clifford algebra attached to a negative-definite quadratic form on $\mathbb R^3$, with $i^2=j^2=k^2=-1$.

The opposite sign, giving $i^2=j^2=k^2=1$, gives the ring of two-by-two real matrices, for example taking $i=\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&-1}$, $j=\pmatrix{0&1\cr1&0}$, etc.

In either case, the "unit quaternions" are those with "reduced norm $1$", which means "determinant=1" in matrix models. So this gives $SL_2(\mathbb R)$ in the latter case.

The units $A^\times$ in a quaternion algebra (over $\mathbb R$) $A$ act on $A\approx \mathbb R^4$ in at least two ways. One is by left (or right) multiplication $a\cdot b=ab$. Another is by conjugation $a\cdot b=aba^{-1}$.